# Why does C-3PO talk to R2-D2 in English?

Tags: star-wars, languages

Whenever we see C-3PO talking to R2-D2, he talks in English (well, that's what we hear) so at least not in the 'binary' beeps that R2-D2 uses.

***Why* doesn't C-3PO talk in R2's 'beeping' language when they're together and there's no need for a translation?**  Surely C-3PO could speak in that language, being both a translator *and* a droid.  I'm looking for in-universe answers, because of course it's done on-screen for our benefit of understanding what R2 is saying!

Comment: so people who watch the movie in English don't need subtitles =P

Comment: and you my friend obviously fail to understand whimsy ;]

Comment: For all we know, nobody in the Star Wars Universe speaks English. I imagine in Japanese movie theaters everybody except R2D2 speaks Japanese.

Comment: @Major Stackings - Well played Major.

Comment: Also, [why doesn't R2 speak English](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8220/why-cant-r2-d2-talk)? It can understand it, so why can't it speak it?

Comment: The real question should be why do they talk to each other at all? They're both robots, it seems unlikely that robots would use something as primitive as spoken word to communicate if technology has advanced as far as it has in the SW universe. Communicating via some sort of machine code or direct transmission of "thoughts" via some kind of far-future-radio-signal-allegory or something like that would be more efficient and much more likely.

Comment: @MajorStackings I'd say it doesn't matter whether C3PO is talking in English, Japanese or Basic. What matters is that he is speaking a _human_ language to a robot which talks in beeps.

Comment: @AndresF. lol. I'd say it's a plot device, but it is easily conceivable that they speak in machine language when there are no humans around (the audience). It's equally possible that C3PO's default programming is set so that when he isn't translating, his basic speech mode is audience speak. I think the real question is why such integral droids as the R2 series seem to be are non conversant in human language.

Comment: Can R2-D2 understand beeps? I think it can only speak in beeps.

Comment: @Dave If robots were allowed to communicate in their own dialect that is far more efficient and practically impossible for any human to understand (given the decoding requirements and factoring in the inherently slower understanding of the biological brain) the non-robot citizens would soon feel themselves threatened by the robots. Imageine how would you feel if everyone was a telepath around you: you could never know what they are talking about or even if they are talking in the first place.

Comment: For the same reason Han Solo doesn't speak Wookieese to Chewbacca: his speech system isn't able to generate the sounds accurately.

Comment: I believe, C3PO being a protocol droid, is just following some protocol to speak in the most common language possible (in this case, BASIC). Not related but at non canon SWTOR astro droids beeps are "subtitled" to ressemble a programing language, example: "R2D2 + Jedi = Forever" for a small droid declaring eternal friendship

Comment: They are robots who can understand many different languages. Of the subset of languages they know, any could be used for conversation equally well. So unlike humans who may be proficient in one language and thus prefer it, they have no preference on that basis. So they just use their default language. The information is just the same, they are language agnostic. Humanising them by thinking they have a preference based on efficiency or proficiency is a mistake imo, they are robots.

Comment: @SachinShekhar R2 units, specifically including R2D2, *are* capable of understanding, as well as speaking, R2 beep language. This is demonstrated in ANH, in the scene where Luke and Uncle Owen buy R2D2 and C3PO: while they are negotiating to buy 3PO and Red, Red, R2D2, and one other droid unit are chattering back and forth to each other in R2 beep language, showing every possible indication (short of being translated) of them understanding each other, leading up to Red responding to R2's expressed views on separation from C3PO, by overloading his motivator to deflect the sale onto R2D2.

Comment: As a droid programmed for etiquette, protocol and "human-cyborg relations", could you imagine how rude it would be to be walked in on speaking in Binary? Imagine the etiquette faux pas it would be to then stop, mid-Binary statement, and shift to Basic? Furthermore, it's not good for "human-cyborg relations" if you're overheard talking in a language few humans know; it would certainly lend to distrust and poor relations. I suspect the 'proper' thing to to for an etiquette droid is to speak in the humans' tongues, even when it appears that no one is around, just for potential eavesdroppers.

Comment: Its Because we know and understand one side conversation... :P :D

Comment: @MajorStackings As a kid, I attended the premiere of RotJ in a Yokohama cinema & they had subtitles. I heard the original English soundtrack. It was awesome.

Comment: Because C3PO was made by a 9 year old slave boy with little idea of how protocol droids should speak? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124897/if-c3po-is-a-protocol-droid-why-is-he-so-annoying

Answer (score 92, accepted):

C-3PO is programmed for etiquette and protocol; so undoubtedly he would speak Galactic Basic to R2-D2 if any others are present, so that everyone can understand what he is saying. However this doesn't explain why he speaks it to R2-D2 when no one else is around, for example when they are alone in the desert wastes of Tatooine.

We know C-3PO prefers some languages to others. In TESB he complains about the Millennium Falcon's communication:

> C-3PO (to Han): Sir, I don't know where your ship learned to
> communicate, but it has the most peculiar dialect.

It is possible he finds R2-D2's "beep language" ugly or has some other prejudice against it. Given his frequent efforts to insult and belittle R2-D2, C-3PO may consider beep language to be beneath him.

Also, as Numaroth says, speaking Galactic Basic may simply be a habit for C-3PO. It appears to be the language he uses to talk and grumble to himself, for example in the opening scene of ANH when he mutters "I'm going to regret this" as he climbs into the escape pod.

One thing which *seems* to be evidence of this, but really isn't, is C-3PO speaking Basic to Jabba the Hutt in ROTJ. According to the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11978/why-does-c-3po-speak-to-jabba-in-basic-english?rq=1), he is not considered worthy to speak Huttese to Jabba and would have been severely punished if he tried.

Comment: Wasn't C-3PO made by Anakin (or at least fixed) in The Phantom Menace? Anakin might have made his own language the default setting (all machines/robots have default settings, after all)

Comment: I like the idea of default settings. I always thought that machine to machine should use bluetooth but that would be rather boring to watch!

Comment: @Andreas: Good point. And the Rebel Alliance also spoke Basic, so they would have left the settings as they were.

Comment: You say "habit," but as a computer programmer I hear the word "default."  If I were programming C-3PO I'd have him use the most default language possible (Basic, in this case) that he and the listener have in common.  It would save a little bit of processing time if his AI didn't have to translate what he was saying into "astromech beep" before sending the phrase to his vocorder.

Comment: Maybe he's talking to himself *about* R2D2 and R2D2 just happens to be there most of the time. He does talk to himself a lot.

Comment: @Andreas I had the same thought myself. R2D2 doesn't seem to care if someone is speaking to him in binary or not, he understands it anyway. That's why C-3PO just goes with the default option.

Comment: @ilinamorato: Interesting, but C-3P0's "mind" is almost certainly not a text file full of Galactic Basic words. Instead he will have a internal mind-state corresponding to, say, "frustration with R2-D2" which he can express in any of 6 million forms of communication.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit: Well, sure, but he almost certainly does have six million dictionaries to translate the binary string of data into actual sounds (and perhaps motions? 'forms of communication' seems to imply more than just speech) that the listener can understand.  The algorithm which chooses that dictionary would have to have a default or fallback.  As Andreas noted, Anakin would likely have set that default to Basic, with the Rebels leaving it as it was, as you noted.

Comment: @ilinamorato: Yes, I understand that. My point was that making Galactic Basic the default language does *not* mean it is any more efficient in terms of processing time. In fact, GB is almost certainly *less* computationally efficient than machine languages which have been optimised with respect to data compression. (And I agree "forms of communication" very likely includes writing, gestures, and other non-verbal modes.)

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit: Yeah, that makes sense.  But he's a protocol droid, and so his primary function is "human-cyborg relations."  As such, he's not going to have a machine language as default.  At that point, it's less about optimization and more about UX.

Answer (score 18):

Obviously, the real reason is for the audience's benefit, but since you want an in-universe I'll do my best.  Be forewarned that I have no sources for this answer.

I would say that the reason C-3PO talks in Galactic Basic to R2-D2 is habit.  It is clear that in the Star Wars universe that droids have personalities and some level of sentience.  With these traits comes the propensity for forming habits.  Since C-3PO spends most of his time conversing in Basic it would become a habit for him to continue to use it even when it was not strictly necessary.  This habit would be reinforced by the fact that it is likely that C-3PO's default language is set to Basic, with him only using something else when necessary.

Plus, when there are other people around C-3PO might choose to use Basic to avoid being rude by having a conversation that the others could not understand.

Comment: Good speculation, but it is just that - speculation.  If you could find any sources to back it up though, I'd be more than happy to accept this as an answer!

Answer (score 12):

A few possibilities:

**This is acceptable etiquette in the Star Wars universe**

In universe, everyone -- not just C-3PO -- speaks in their own language of choice, and the person they're talking to replies in their own language. Linguistic aptitude is apparently normal, at least in terms of understanding. (And, for the cases where it isn't, Protocol Droids). The same is done with Han/Chewie, Han/Greedo, et cetera. It is normal.

**C-3PO is demonstrating superiority over R2-D2**

R2-D2 cannot speak English. C-3PO can, and is a bit petty. He would never turn down a chance to rub his superiority in R2's face, but since R2 doesn't really have a face, he has to settle for this.

**R2-D2's Language Is Just Profanity**

The beeps are not from R2-D2, but from the censors. C-3PO is far too protocol-adhering to use such language, and the movies didn't want the X-rating that his graphic language would have required -- so we hear beeps, but everyone else hears profanity.

Comment: +1 for the first two. -1 for not making it clear enough that the third is a joke. net effect: no vote.

Comment: Are you saying R2D2 swears more than the mechanic who fixes my car?

Answer (score 7):

There is one very simple explanation.

Even if R2-D2 cannot speak Galactic, it obviously understands it perfectly. All humans give it orders in Galactic anyway.

There is no reason why C-3PO should speak in the "beep" language then.

Comment: This could go either way. Given a set of languages that R2D2 can understand, why choose *any* of them? If there are no humans present, why would C3PO default to Galactic if R2D2 speaks in "beep"? My computer doesn't talk to my router in English for my benefit...

Comment: @AndresF. I think that is the point. C3PO could arbitrarily use any language that R2 knows, so his decision to use Galactic is mostly arbitrary. He probably arbitrarily does this out of habit because that is what C3PO uses with with most other characters and what most other characters use with R2, but it is arbitrary.

Comment: I like this explanation best. R2D2 understands Galactic (and presumably many other languages) fine.  So there is no need for C3PO to necessarily speak beep to him. It is reasonable that C3PO defaults to the most common galactic language.

Answer (score 4):

C-3PO has a very emotional and extroverted personality. He seems to prefer Galactic Basic because it seems to be a good language to express his emotions.

But considering that R2-D2 is designed for much more technical tasks, one can assume that his beeping language is designed primarily for expressing technical concepts. It might lack the vocabulary and inflections for expressing emotions well. That means it simply doesn't allow C-3PO to say what he wants to say, or at least not efficiently.

Let's take the first line C-3PO speaks to R2-D2 in *A New Hope*:

> Did you hear that? They shut down the main reactor. We will be destroyed for sure. This is madness!

The information that a technical device was shut off and that there is a high risk of non-functionality in the near future can surely be expressed easily in beep-code, because they are useful information for the work of an astromech droid. But the reason C-3PO says this is not because he wants to inform R2-D2 about technical facts. What C-3PO actually wants to express is *how this makes him feel*. He doesn't communicate this by *what* he says but by *how* he says it. The beep-code language might simply not allow this.

When he would try to convey all the information hidden in inflection in the actual text, the beep-code would likely literally translate like this:

> **Did you hear that?** I am certain you did and do not expect you to answer. However, this sound made me really startled and I feel the desire to use it as an occasion to discuss our current situation with you. **They shut down the main reactor.** I believe that this is a very unwise decision in the current situation. However, I do not believe that they would follow my advise, because they usually do not. The continuous under-appreciation of my technical expertise is frustrating to me. **We will be destroyed for sure.** I am very afraid of being destroyed. But I do not see a way for me to prevent this from happening. This makes me feel very helpless and desperate. **This is madness!** I wish all the humans would understand that their violent actions only lead to unnecessary suffering and that friendly cooperation is a much more logical course of action. However, I understand that I will never be able to convince them of this fact. This makes me feel small and inadequate in the great order of things. What is your emotional reaction to the current situation?

Encoding and speaking this whole text in beep-code would likely take longer than speaking it in Galactic Basic. And that under the assumption that it even has words for concepts like "frustration", "fear" or "desperation". Without such words C-3PO would further have to paraphrase these concepts somehow, which would make the text even longer.

Answer (score 2):

While C-3PO understands the beeps it might be the case that he isn't able (technically or otherwise) able to speak it.

Comment: But he's fluent in over 6 million forms of communication....

Comment: This is still a valid answer unless we have evidence that C3PO can speak 'beep' but for whatever reason decides not to.

Comment: Perhaps he is doing it to piss off R2D2.

Comment: In Episode VI when C3PO tells their story to the Ewoks, he is able to accurately reproduce various sound effects. I would find it very unlikely that he is technically capable to make the sound of a laser gun but not of R2's beep-code language.

Answer (score 1):

I may need to review the scenes again, but when he was "speaking" to the Millennium Falcon, even then he used Galactic Basic, rather than whatever it was the Falcon "spoke", even though supposedly a binary language would be easier to communicate in for a strictly-digital being.

My theory therefore (and this is somewhat speculation) is that C-3PO *can't* speak Binary, any more than R2 could speak Basic, or Chewbacca could win a beauty contest (because he's an outlaw. Chewie was really hurt that they turned his application down).

This would make sense - R2 has to speak to computers all the time in his line of work, but a Protocol droid, built for diplomatic missions and courtesy, would have no reason to speak to machines, given what we've seen in the way people treat them - generally as second-class citizens at best, and property at most common.

In short, C-3PO probably can't even speak in R2's language.  He may know what it means, since being able to relay a droid message could be important, but he's just not programmed to speak it.

Comment: "One of my first jobs was programming binary load lifters, very similar to your moisture evaporators in many respects"

Comment: @Josh 'Programming binary load lifters' is a far cry from 'being able to speak to them'.  That, and I always assumed C3P0 was, in that scene, making that up to get himself free from the Jawas.

Comment: Look a little closer. C3PO's comment wasn't just "One of my first jobs was programming binary load lifters, very similar to your moisture evaporators in many respects", as Josh quotes. He starts with "Oh, yes, one of my...", and that "Oh yes" was in direct response to Uncle Owen inquiring, not just about translating the output from the moisture evaporators, but *specifically* about "can speak the binary language of" those evaporators.

Comment: @MatthewNajmon I haven't seen the movie recently, but I believe the question was "can *understand* the binary language of moisture vaporators", not "can *speak* the binary language of moisture vaporators".

Comment: @Zibbobz Possibly. I remember it as "speak", but I don't have the movie at hand at the moment to check.

Answer (score 1):

There is no in-universe answer. Of course people can come up with them, but there is no canonical source to confirm them. Therefore, by Occam's Razor, we must accept the most obvious reason: that it's done for the viewer's benefit, even if you don't like this answer.

Comment: There are already 4 answers to this question, so clearly an in-universe answer can be given. Just because it's never explicitly stated in canon, it doesn't mean you can't analyse the evidence, and come to a logical conclusion.

Comment: You can give it, but if you follow my reasoning, it will most likely be wrong. Remember that Star Wars was and is first and foremost an entertainment product; closing your eyes to the very obvious fact that the filmmakers just wanted to produce an accessible and entertaining movie, even if it means contradicting the in-world logic, is just silly. This is especially true when you consider that much of the worldbuilding hadn't happened at the time of the first movie yet and was retconned later.

Comment: Even if there is no in-universe answer, you can still explore the evidence before coming to that conclusion. Point out the discrepancies and inconsistencies, rather than just stating "there's no reason for it". Saying "for the viewer's benefit" without exploring evidence and possibilities isn't really an acceptable answer. It could be applied to just about every work of SF&F that exists. Particularly when the asker specifically states "I'm looking for in-universe answers, because of course it's done on-screen for our benefit of understanding what R2 is saying".

Answer (score 1):

One possible in-universe explanation is that C-3PO created on Tatooine and R2-D2 manufactured on Naboo have no common interface to communicate. 
The only way they can communicate is through the language of their masters which is used for human/robot communication.
Hence C-3PO has to use this common langauge with R2-D2 even when they are alone.

Comment: C3PO clearly understands R2D2's "beeps", but this explanation works if for some reason he can't speak it. Maybe his sound card just isn't up to emitting it :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop, it is possible that the "beeps" are a far more subtle and complex form of communication than we give them credit: they may encompass harmonics at frequencies the audience cannot register. (Human hearing works best between 20 Hz and 20 kHz.) Assuming C3PO was designed for communicating with human-like species, his hardware may not be able to output the required sounds.

Answer (score 0):

You could equally ask how everyone understands Chewie's growls. For Han it'd be years of being around him just as a dog can be "understood" by its master over time and friends adapt to other friends' languages. In Luke's case the Force would probably help him initially. Luke and R2 is more difficult though. The Force might be at play, or more likely Luke is the one who "understands the binary language" and clearly has his father's affinity and skill with machines... and that's why Owen wants a droid, he either doesn't want to rely on Luke or knows he can't forever and part of his "bargain" with Luke about the academy is to get the droid that does it... almost a "show of faith," figuring if the droid is there Luke will knuckle down for a bit longer and give him time to talk him out of the academy.

With C-3PO and R2 it would be the easiest common language for the two, I take the idea that C-3PO doesn't "talk to machines", it makes sense that that's not his "job" and as he is a bit haughty and boastful, it is likely he can do it but not well, so he doesn't cos R2 can understand Basic as he has been programmed to take verbal orders rather than in any other language to stop him being reprogrammed by other machines, it's why Jawas have to use restraining bolts.

Comment: Everyone understanding Chewie's growls is beside the issue, right? The question is not how can C3PO understand R2D2, but why does he default to Galactic when speaking to it, instead of using beeps. (Going back to your example: I bet Han would find it uncomfortable or physically impossible to growl back at Chewie, but that's not the case for C3PO and beep language!)

Comment: @AndresF. how do we actually know that that's not the case for C3PO and beep language? it's fairly well established that C3PO *can* speak beep language, but I don't see how it's particularly well established at all that he doesn't find doing so to be uncomfortable, physically or, more likely, socially, for him to do so.

Comment: @MatthewNajmon Sure! That might very well be the actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no indication that C-3PO is speaking in English at all (or Galactic Base).  If you accept the premise that:

- Galactic Base is *not* English
- All the characters are not speaking English
- The films translate their speech to English for us

Then there's no reason to think C-3PO is not speaking a machine language to R2-D2 when they're alone.

Which give us another question: Why does R2-D2 speak in beeps?

- I propose that we only hear beeps in the movie to indicate that he (it?) is not being understood by the main characters.

**tl;dr summary: What we hear in the movie is a translation, not the actual language**

Also see: https://www.tor.com/blogs/2014/04/every-human-in-star-wars-is-really-a-humanoid-bee

Comment: This is probably not it. In any given scene we can assume a speech translation to English/Japanese/whatever (depending on the audience), but what you *cannot* have is one character whose speech is translated (C3PO in your example) and another one speaking the *same* language untranslated in the *same scene* (R2D2). This doesn't make sense: in any given scene, you either translate beep language for all characters or you don't for any.

Comment: @AndresF.: Some real-world electronic devices that connect to the telephone network have hardware which can produce intelligible speech, and others have hardware which can produce machine-recognizable sounds but aren't sophisticated enough to produce speech.  Why would it be implausible that R2D2 would lack the audio hardware necessary for live characters to understand it?

Comment: @supercat Of course I understand that R2D2 cannot speak Galactic because he doesn't have the hardware for it. I merely said that it's not possible for C3PO to be speaking in beeps and R2D2 answering in beeps *and* the movie scene only has C3PO's speech translated to English.

Comment: @AndresF.: Even if C3PO were to speak in beeps when nobody else was around, translating as human language would still make sense to emphasize the point that C3PO endeavors to avoid communicating in such fashion as to be incomprehensible to humans present.

Comment: @supercat I don't think that's how it works in movie-making. In fact I can't remember a single movie where two characters are both speaking the *same language* in the *same scene* but only one of them gets dubbed/subtitled. It would get very confusing for the audience, and what would be the point anyway?

Comment: Frankly you can't think too hard about why R2D2 speaks in beeps. He's intelligent and self aware. My phone can speak to me for crying out loud and it certainly can't think for itself or repair spacecraft.

Comment: @AndresF.: I was thinking of it as a "tree falling in the woods" thing; C3PO might speak in beeps when unobserved by humans, but no human (*including the audience*) would ever observe that.  Also, while I can't think of cinematic examples, I've certainly seen television shows where two people were speaking the same language and only one was subtitled, typically because one was more understandable than the other.  Perhaps one could stretch that rationale here--R2D2's dialect of "digital" includes a level of human-recognizable expression sufficient that the audience can understand it...

Comment: ...to some degree; it may be that because C3PO would only speak digital for a purely-droid audience, the dialect might not be understandable to the audience if it weren't dubbed.

Answer (score 0):

You won't like it but the first *Star Wars* feature was filmed (1977) prior to the adoption of personal computers and resultant high level language code such as C/C++ (1979 for C++).  The thought of a default machine code likely never entered into the writer's/producer's thought process.

C-3PO communicates with R2-D2 in English because that is what he did in the first movie because the thought of "Machine Code" hadn't been widely understood/adopted.

In universe, Basic is faster to articulate than Beep and thus more efficient.  Machines are always all about efficiency.  It takes processing power and (whatever C-3PO's normal power supply is) to translate and verbalize the Beep language so it would be much more efficient to simply speak in Basic.

Just my $.02

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is just rubbish. To begin with, high level programming languages have been around since the late 1950s (C++ is the fourth language in one of the many HLL lineages). Secondly, programming languages aren't for communication: a communications protocol would be a closer analogy for what droids would use. Such protocols were also present in the late 1970s. Thirdly, there is simply no way that Basic is more computation-efficient than "Beep". If this were the case, R2D2 would certainly be speaking Basic instead.

Comment: My previous comment stands, but I apologize for using the word "rubbish", that was quite uncalled for.

Comment: I totally do not understand why you seem to consider it a reasonable assumption that C3PO does not speak in some beep code language because such technology was not widespread when the movie was made, while R2D2 actually does in the same movie.